# Closing > Off-topic > Migration... Why only to meta.SE?

Tags: support

I reviewed [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/40761/13418) and I thought it should be migrated to RPG.SE, but the only site I could indicate it should be migrated to was the meta, why?

Scifi is related to a lot of sites, MOVIES, ANIME, RPG, sometime PHYSICS... why could I choose only the meta one?

Is it a privilege matter? I think we should be able to indicate more sites.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Migration Paths](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/migration-paths), see also http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3077/close-reason-this-question-belongs-on-another-site-in-the-stack-exchange-networ

Answer (score 3):

There can be up to 5 predefined migration paths for each Stack Exchange site - by default only the meta site is there, as, for any new site it is unclear what the other 4 should be, if at all.

Note that for a question to be migrated 4 out of 5 off-topic close votes would have to agree on both the need to migrate and the migration target. Moderators can migrate to *any* other site (but would normally only do so after consulting with the moderators of the suggested target site) without a need for a consensus vote.

If you feel that there are other Stack Exchange sites that come up often enough as migration targets, this is something that can be addressed by the Stack Exchange community team - I suggest putting up a Meta post asking for those migration paths.